# Present scene from file in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have level1 presented from GameViewController using `unarchiveFromFile`. But how can I present level2 from `sks` file?

I mean only present level2 and use it with level1 code, because here I have all game logic.

**EDIT:**

I present my scene from sks file like this:

**GameViewController.m**

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

And I would like to present another scene from another SKS file from `GameScene.m` file. And I can't call `unarchieveFromFile` from `GameScene.m`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are casting it as the object that you want to be using

```
GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("Level1") as? GameScene;
GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("Level2") as? GameScene;
```

Where `GameScene` is the swift class that you want to be using for your logic

Comment: Wait, I would need to call it from my GameViewController, because I can't use unarchievefromfile from my gameScene. I would have to use some kind of delegate?

Comment: Show some code so I  can understand what you are doing